# Is it possible to perform i/o from within JENA rules?

Tags: jena, apache-jena, jena-rules

I'm interested in using Jena to build a fault diagnostic, ontology-based expert system. Is it possible to perform i/o from within forward- or backward-chaining rules? For example to prompt the user for further facts? Or to access a database?

Comment: Sure, you just write a built-in that does some I/O.  There are already built-ins that do output (like printing).    Did something not work about this approach?

Comment: Thanks! I am just researching which tool to use and have struggled with I/O in other tools, so just wanted to check its feasibility in Jena.